# Convert the glmnet predict function in R to Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, glmnet, rcpparmadillo

I have a question on converting the glmnet `predict` in R to Rcpp.

Currently I do this in R:

```
set.seed(0)

x1 <- matrix(runif(20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
y1 <- runif(4)


lasso_model <- glmnet(x1, y1, alpha = 1 ,lower.limits = 0, intercept = FALSE)
cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x1, y1, alpha = 1, lower.limits = 0)
optimal_lambda <- cv_model$lambda.min
# Get the coefficients for the optimal lambda
coefficients_vector <- predict(lasso_model, s = c(optimal_lambda), type = "coefficients")
# get the actual coefficients start from the second element
coefficients_vector <- coefficients_vector[-1,]
coefficients_vector
```

and I want to create a Rcpp function, here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec glmnetWithCV(const arma::mat& x, const arma::vec& y) {
  // Use the global environment to find glmnet functions
  Environment glmnet_env = Environment::namespace_env("glmnet");
  Function cv_glmnet = glmnet_env["cv.glmnet"];
  Function glmnet = glmnet_env["glmnet"];
  Function predict_glmnet = glmnet_env["predict"];
  
  NumericMatrix x_rcpp = wrap(x);
  NumericVector y_rcpp = wrap(y);
  
  // Fit the Lasso model
  List lasso_model = glmnet(Named("x") = x_rcpp, Named("y") = y_rcpp, Named("alpha") = 1, Named("lower.limits") = 0);
  
  // Perform cross-validation to find the optimal lambda
  List cv_model = cv_glmnet(Named("x") = x_rcpp, Named("y") = y_rcpp, Named("alpha") = 1, Named("lower.limits") = 0);

  NumericVector optimal_lambda = as<double>(cv_model["lambda.min"]);
  //Rcout << "Optimal lambda: " << optimal_lambda << std::endl;

  S4 coefficients_vector = predict_glmnet(lasso_model, Named("s") = optimal_lambda, Named("type") = "coefficients");

  return List::create(Named("coefficients") = coefficients_vector, 
                      Named("optimal_lambda") = optimal_lambda);
}
```

But I found I got error on passing  `S4 coefficients = predict_glmnet(lasso_model, Named("s") = optimal_lambda, Named("type") = "coefficients");`, when in R the  `coefficients_vector`  is a `dcgMatrix`, I have tried using sp_mat from arma, but it still don't work.

I'm wondering if there is any solution on this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Why would you want to call R into C++ then back to R? Prediction should be even faster than model fitting. Rcpp is for speed and it seems you're not interested in that. Consider doing everything in R

Comment: I'm actually considering speed, because I'm planning to do the simulation on fitting different x1 and y1 1000 times.

Comment: Then the prediction has nothing to do with speed but rather the fitting part. You will have to either rewrite the whole glmnet function in Rcpp which is complex and tedious or look for a package that does the same in C++ and use that. Also I believe glmnet should have most of its fitting task written in C/C++, you could make use of that

Comment: Calling an R function from C++, as you do here, is not faster than calling it from R.  You are still running the same R code.